# Convert "sex = 0" in JSON to a BOOL

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, boolean

I have [a small iPhone app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthMailru/), which fetches user information (name, city, gender) from a social network and then displays it in a view:

[image: app screenshot]

The data arrives in JSON format (please note the `sex = 0` for male users):

```
2014-01-22 21:18:42.915 oauthMailru[697:1303] json=(
        {
        age = 41;
        "app_installed" = 1;
        birthday = "08.06.1972";
        "first_name" = Alexander;
        "friends_count" = 17;
        "has_pic" = 1;
        "is_friend" = 0;
        "is_online" = 0;
        "is_verified" = 1;
        "last_name" = Farber;
        "last_visit" = 1390312557;
        link = "http://my.mail.ru/mail/farber72/";
        location =         {
            city =             {
                id = 855;
                name = "Dusseldorf";
            };
            country =             {
                id = 46;
                name = "Germany";
            };
        };
        nick = "Alexander Farber";
        pic = "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/farber72/_avatar";
        "pic_big" = "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/farber72/_avatarbig";
        "pic_small" = "http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/farber72/_avatarsmall";
        "referer_id" = "";
        "referer_type" = "";
        sex = 0;
        "show_age" = 1;
        uid = 17880121030128875114;
        vip = 0;
    }
)
```

And then I print it in my [DetailViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthMailru/oauthMailru/DetailViewController.m):

```
2014-01-22 21:18:42.920 oauthMailru[697:70b] id: 17880121030128875114
2014-01-22 21:18:42.920 oauthMailru[697:70b] first_name: Alexander
2014-01-22 21:18:42.921 oauthMailru[697:70b] last_name: Farber
2014-01-22 21:18:42.921 oauthMailru[697:70b] city: Dusseldorf
2014-01-22 21:18:42.921 oauthMailru[697:70b] female: 1
2014-01-22 21:18:42.922 oauthMailru[697:70b] avatar: http://avt.appsmail.ru/mail/farber72/_avatarbig
```

My code parsing the JSON input is in [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthMailru/oauthMailru/ViewController.m) and assigns it to [User.h](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/oauthMailru/oauthMailru/User.h) properties:

```
         NSDictionary *dict = json[0];

         _user = [[User alloc] init];
         _user.userId    = dict[@"uid"];
         _user.firstName = dict[@"first_name"];
         _user.lastName  = dict[@"last_name"];
         _user.city      = dict[@"location"][@"city"][@"name"];
         _user.avatar    = dict[@"pic_big"];
         _user.female    = !(BOOL)dict[@"sex"];
```

For some reason the last User property - the BOOL `female` is always set wrong for me.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
         _user.female    = !(BOOL)dict[@"sex"];
         _user.female    = (0 != dict[@"sex"]);
         _user.female    = (int)dict[@"sex"];
```

Can anybody please advise, how to cast the `id` to `BOOL` here properly?

Comment: Without the `(int)` cast you would have got the compiler warning *"incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an expression of type 'id'"* which shows the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't cast objects to primitives in Objective C (`id`s are object pointers) . Assuming your JSON parser parses the numbers into NSNumbers you'd just have to do:

```
![dict[@"sex"] boolValue]
```

Comment: Thanks, but `![dict[@"sex"] boolValue]` delivers me `female` for some weird reason

Comment: Does `[dict[@"sex"] boolValue]` == male?

Comment: is male == 1 and female == 0? how is (fe)male defined in your code?

Comment: assuming female is 1, an NSNumber with a value of 1 will return YES from boolValue. YES is equivalent to 1 so !1 is 0.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: If in doubt, split the computation into separate steps: `NSNumber *val = dict[@"sex"]; BOOL b = [val boolValue]; _user.female = !b;`. Set a breakpoint and inspect each variable.

Answer (score 2):

`dict[@"sex"]` isn't a BOOL, it's an `NSNumber`, so you want:

```
![dict[@"sex"] boolValue]
```

Comment: `id` is just an object pointer. so `dict[@"sex"]` is an `id`, `NSObject *`, and an `NSNumber *`.

Comment: `id` is a general reference to any object type. It isn't a specific type, like `NSNumber`. You're mixing up the return type of a method (which from the dictionary is `id`) and the actual instance behind that.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
_user.female = ([dict[@"sex"] intValue]>0)
```

Comment: do not forget the ';' at the end =)